# Angular 7 Form cancel

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular-forms

Please look the sample code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9udyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have 2 textbox with 2way data binding. i get the data from api service call and then i populate the form.

Can you please suggest me how to retain old value from modified form field while clicking cancel button

For example

form rendered with some text

#textbox1 = 'apple'
  #textbox2 = 'orange'

User change the form fields

#textbox1='asdfg'

#textbox2='lkj'

then User click cancel button.

I want to retain previous data #textbox1='apple' #textbox2='orange'

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just keep a duplicate of the data when you get it from the server and on cancel reuse this data?

Comment: how to duplicate the object like deep clone

Comment: is it possible to duplicate ngForm object in ngOnInit() life cycle hook

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a copy of the data so your class looks something like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    
   textbox1;
   textbox2;
   textbox1Save;
   textbox2Save;

   onDataFromApi() {
     /* values from API call */
     this.textbox1 = this.textbox1Save = 'Angular';
     this.textbox2 = this.textbox2Save = 'Angular';  
  }

  cancel() {
    this.textbox1 = this.textbox1Save;
    this.textbox1 = this.textbox2Save;
    alert('data cancel')
  }
}
```

#### Edit to answer for keeping data in an object

So it's even easier if you keep the data in an object. When you get the data from the server just clone it: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj))`

```
export class AppComponent  {
    
   obj = {
    textbox1: '',
    textbox2: ''
  }
  
  onDataFromApi() {
     /* values from API call */
     this.copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj));
  }

  cancel() {
    this.obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.copy));
    alert('data cancel')
  }
}
```

#### Edit:

You can get the form data by using:

`@ViewChild('myForm', { static: false }) myForm;`

and then this.myForm.value where you want the values.

Be careful that myForm will be `undefined` untill `AfterViewInit` has ran.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('myForm', { static: false }) myForm;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    /* until here this.myForm will be undefined
       After, you can get the data using myForm.value
    */
  }

  onDataFromApi() {
     /* values from API call */
     this.copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj));
  }

  cancel() {
    this.obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.copy));
    alert('data cancel')
  }

}
```

Also you will have to have different `"name"` for each form field. In your example you have `name="text"` for both inputs.

Comment: thanks for your response.      let assume i have 50 dynamic fields how can i do it?    is it possible to duplicate ngForm object in ngOnInit() life cycle hook

Comment: How do you keep the fields? Each in its own variable or in an object or an array?

Comment: let assume object of array i

Comment: is it possible to duplicate ngForm object in ngOnInit() life cycle hook

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by duplicating the data on the OnInit hook. Do you make the API call on your ngOnInit function? If so, yes, you can create a deep copy of the data using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj))`.

Comment: ok fine. one more last question how to detect form field loaded and form object created in component i want to take form value in Ngform using form.value

Comment: can you please tell how to wait until form get loaded in 'ngAfterViewInit()'

Comment: i done thanks   return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(this.myForm.value);
      });
    });

Comment: @AngularDev Glad it helped. So if this answer is what you needed, please consider marking it as accepted.